# conditions on python when i check hard bounces email

Tags: python, smtp

i write Python script to verify hard bounces

```
from validate_email import validate_email

with open("test.txt") as fp:  
    line = fp.readline()
    cnt = 1
    while line:
        line = fp.readline()
        print ('this email :' + str(line) +'status : ' + str((validate_email(line,verify=True))))
        stt=str(validate_email(line,verify=True))
        email=str(line)
        print ("-----------------") 
        cnt += 1
        if stt == "True":
            file=open("clean.txt",'w+')
            file.write(email)
        if stt == "None":
            file=open("checkagain.txt",'w+')
            file.write(email)
        if stt == "False":
            file=open("bounces.txt",'w+')
            file.write(email)
```

for False condition it create the file but no emails inside even if am sure that i have bounces emails

Comment: do you close the file? You should be using `with open('bounces.txt', 'a') as file:`

Comment: Also: calling `fp.readline()` twice means you skip every second line.

Comment: What's the input? Just one email address per line?

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the file to reflect your changes in file, put:

```
file.close()
```

at the end

you should instead be using:

```
with open('bounces.txt', 'a') as file:
# your file operations
```

that way you wont have to close the file

Answer (score 0):

Your script contains a number of errors.

- Each input line contains a trailing newline.
- Opening the same file for writing multiple times is hideously inefficient. Failing to close the files is what caused them to end up empty. Reopening without closing might end up discarding things you've written on some platforms.
- Several operations are repeated, some merely introducing inefficiencies, others outright errors.

Here is a refactoring, with inlined comments on the changes.

```
from validate_email import validate_email

# Open output files just once, too
with open("test.txt") as fp, \
        open('clean.txt', 'w') as clean, \
        open('checkagain.txt', 'w') as check, \
        open('bounces.txt', 'w') as bounces:
    # Enumerate to keep track of line number
    for i, line in enumerate(fp, 1):
        # Remove trailing newline
        email = line.rstrip()
        # Only validate once; don't coerce to string
        stt = validate_email(email, verify=True)
        # No need for str()
        print ('this email:' + email +'status: ' + stt)
        # Really tempted to remove this, too...
        print ("-----------------")
       # Don't compare to string
        if stt == True:
            clean.write(line)
       elif stt == None:
            check.write(line)
        elif stt == False:
            bounces.write(line)
```

You are not using the line number for anything, but I left it in to show how it's usually done.